# Query insert into table it's error does not exist

Tags: sql-insert

This query, how come it throws an error when it's run?

> SQL Error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
> table or view does not exist

```
insert into new_end_kontrak2_all_202308
    select a.*, null, null 
    from NEW_END_KONTRAK2 a;
```